# MVC auto complete inputs according to recent user entries

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a site that manages a database.

Lets say the users enter information about people (height, weight, name etc...)
A lot of people are entered each day and the height range is quite small so if a user entered a person with a certain height I want it to auto complete next time he enters a person.
(like most login forms where you click a textbox and it shows your recent entered login info and when you start typing it auto completes you).

I am using MVC 4 and the person entry is not within a form. When a user clicks save it uses ajax to save.

I know it works with forms but how can I do it on certain textboxes which arent in a form.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) solution doesn't require fields to be in a form.

If you look at the source code of the sample, the previous data is stored as a JavaScript array.  You could store previous entries for each user in a database and then use this data to build an JSON array that can be passed via a view-model to the view and then use `jQuery.parseJSON()` to render it straight into place in the JavaScript.

Comment: I actually meant for the information to be stored on the browser like gmail login or google search

Comment: In that case you probably want to add the attribute `autocomplete="on"` on your HTML input element.  But as far as I know, this will probably only work if the HTML input element is within a HTML form element.